# update mysql latest version from yum

Tags: mysql, centos, vps, yum

I want to update mysql in my VPS from yum.

However I only got 5.0.9 mysql version

Which repository should I add to get mysql latest version. at least 5.1?
(CentOS)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the latest Remi repository

```
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/el5.i386/remi-release-5-6.el5.remi.noarch.rpm
```

Run the rpm install command

```
rpm -Uvh remi-release-5*.rpm
```

It's worth to note that as soon as you use a 3rd party repository to update some of you core packages, you 
won't be able to get any support for it, as the packagers of CentOS cannot test CentOS with all the different packages out there.

Read this page as well to learn about more 3rd repositories:
http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories

(I am using remi myself and I never had a problem, do not enable this repository and if you do so then use `yum-priorities` and set this repository with a lower priority than your centos repositories)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines in a file named remi.repo under /etc/yum.repos.d directory:

```
[remi]
name=Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux 5 - $basearch
baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/el5.$basearch/
http://remi.collet.free.fr/rpms/el5.$basearch/
http://iut-info.univ-reims.fr/remirpms/el5.$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
failovermethod=priority

[remi-test]
name=Les RPM de remi en test pour Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/test-el5.$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
```

Run the follow command:

```
yum --enablerepo remi update mysql
OR
yum --disablerepo \* --enablerepo remi update mysql
```

To check if it was installed, do a:

```
rpm -q mysql
```